# A variable is not being set in my PHP code

Tags: php

I am having issues submitting content from my form to my database. When using `isset` function, it showing that the variables are not being set.

Here is my PHP code and html code.

PHP

```
<?PHP
$title = $_POST['title']['name']; 
if(isset($title)) {
    echo 'all is well';
} else {
    echo 'all is not well';
}

?>
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="newEmptyPHP.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="title">
        <input type="text" name="artist" placeholder="artist">
        <input type="file" name="cover" placeholder="Upload Picture">
        <input type="file" name="song" placeholder="Upload Song">
    </form> 
</div>
```

When I refresh the browser I am receiving "all is not well". What am I missing?

Comment: It's $_POST['title']. Also, method = "POST";

Comment: Also, you don't need to use isset, just $title is fine. Like this: if ($title)

Comment: You can cook it down with usage of a ternary operator, which is a one-liner for that, like this: `echo (isset($_POST['title']) ? "All is well!" : "All is not well..");` -- your `title` in the form isn't an array, so you *must* use `$_POST['title']` and *nothing* more to get that value.

Comment: The `name` attribute's value is the `$_POST`'s index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PHP, `$_POST['title']` should be used to get the value of the title input.

Also, you should always check if the variable in `$_POST` is set before assigning it to a variable.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['title'])) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
}

if($title) {
    echo 'all is well';
}else{
    echo 'all is not well';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This line caused an error: `$title = $_POST['title']['name'];`.

`$_POST` should be followed by the HTML `name` attribute, in your case, `name="title"`.

Also, you should check if the form is posted before assigning it to a variable.

Thus, it should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['title'])) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
```